# Creating clickable file references in a Unix shell terminal

Tags: shell, unix

When I open a shell terminal and type 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' the shell converts this to a clickable url hyperlink.

When I open a shell terminal and type 'file:///Users/msmith/log.txt' the shell converts this to a clickable file hyperlink.

I want to make a link to a file in the console relative to the working directory.

I tried:

```
file:///./<filename> 
file://./<filename> 
file:/./<filename> and 
file:./<filename>
```

but nothing worked.

How do I make a hyperlink to a file using a relative path?

Comment: It depends what terminal you are using. `file:///./<filename>` works fine in `xfce4-terminal`, for example, but the others fail. `xterm` doesn't link **any** urls by default. Apparently terminals using VTE may support an escape-sequence to create links: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda

Comment: How would the browser know what it's relative to?